# convert date dd/mm/yy to the weekday

Tags: python

I have a list of date in the format DD/MM/YYYY, I need to make a list of for example how many sunday's are in the original list, but I have absolutely no idea of where to start, my assignment says to use the datetime module. I am not looking for the answer but a general direction of where to start because at the moment I am lost.

Comment: If you should use the `datetime` "module", then the bash tag is almost certainly wrong. Did you mean python? In that case [the docs for `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) are a good starting point.

Comment: @L3viathan yes I think so, let me change it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the day of week given a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date)

Comment: if your input is string, see also [Python timestamp from day, month, year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9223905/10197418)

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 24, 23, 13, 12).weekday() # Example 1
datetime.datetime.today().weekday()                  # Example 2
```

Returns an integer. Monday is zero, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, wanted to provide two examples.