# How to format +xxxx for strptime()

Tags: python, time, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)

I have string like [22/Aug/2012:13:08:27 +0400] and how I can convert it in time tuple with strptime function?

```
time.strptime(t, '[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S +0400]')
```

works but obviously I need format time offset too.

And when I try format +0400 with %Z, I have:

```
ValueError: time data '[22/Aug/2012:13:08:27 +0400]' does not match format '[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %Z]'
```

and when I try %z

```
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, [`time.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) does not support the `%z` formatter.

The [`dateutil` module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil/) includes a parser that does support parsing timezones.