# Python DateTime Format Error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am new at Python. I was trying to play with time and date objects. I wrote a simple test program to parse a string into a specific time format. But its throwing a `ValueError`. Can you please help me out here?

Here is the code:

```
import time
testDate = "Tuesday, Febuary 23 2011 12:00:00 UTC"
today = time.strptime(testDate,"%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
print today
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\PythonTest\src\helloWorld.py", line 3, in <module>
    today = time.strptime(testDate,"%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\_strptime.py", line 467, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
   (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Tuesday, Febuary 23 2011 12:00:00 UTC' does not match format '%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had February misspelled. Your code works.

```
import time
testDate = "Tuesday, February 23 2011 12:00:00 UTC"
today = time.strptime(testDate,"%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
print today
```

Comment: "Febuary" Ok that was unfortunate.. Actually i am getting time from RSS Feed and its throwing this error.
I changed the date to 
    testDate = "Tuesday, January 24 2012 13:00:00 EST"
This is the exact date from RSS feed and again i get the above error.

Comment: Here is the similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: you spelled "February" wrong:

```
import time
testDate = "Tuesday, February 23 2011 12:00:00 UTC"
today = time.strptime(testDate,"%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
print today
```

Originally, you had "February" spelled as "Febuary".  Works fine once that is fixed.

Comment: "Febuary" Ok that was unfortunate.. Actually i am getting time from RSS Feed and its throwing this error.
I changed the date to 
    testDate = "Tuesday, January 24 2012 13:00:00 EST"
This is the exact date from RSS feed and again i get the above error.

Comment: @planet260 - I fixed _that_ error by changing "EST" to "UTC".  Apparently, the system only works in UTC time.