# Django Python - Convert to datetime from Wed Dec 14 2016 14:39:16 GMT+0300 (AST)

Tags: python, django, datetime, backend

I have a function in my backend and I receive the date from the front end in the formart Wed Dec 14 2016 14:39:16 GMT+0300 (AST)

```
date = request.body['date']
d = datetime.strptime(date, '%a %b %d %Y %X %Z%z')
```

I know strptime converts to the datetime object but I keep getting the following

```
'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %d %Y %X %Z%z'
```

What should my string format be?

Comment: The `%z` directive was added in Python 3.2

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is python 2.7 @MosesKoledoye

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8525115/2549021) to know how to use `python-dateutil` for parsing date time with timezone info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python strptime() and timezones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("Wed Dec 14 2016 14:39:16 GMT+0300 (AST)")
```