# How to convert a string to datetime object

Tags: python

With the time value being:

```
value = '2017-08-31T02:24:29.000Z'
```

I try to convert it to a `datetime` object with:

```
import datetime 
datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%b-%d  %I:%M%p')
```

But the command crashes with the exception:

```
ValueError: time data '2017-08-31T02:24:29.000Z' does not match format '%Y-%b-%d  %I:%M%p'
```

Comment: The error message says the time value is `Jun 1 2005  1:33PM`, but the question says it's `2017-08-31T02:24:29.000Z`.  Which is it?

Comment: Good eye! Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime).

Comment: The error message is exactly correct; the format string does not match the date value you're trying to convert.  For example, the format string contains `%b`, which is supposed to be an abbreviated month name such as `Aug`.  But your time value string uses a number for the month, not a name.

Comment: Aren't you missing the T and a colon plus some of other things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are missing the formatter for the microsecond.

Second of all, there is no second colon for dividing the minute and second.

Third, the `%b` operator is for the monthname (Jan,Feb,etc.). You want to use `%m`.

Final format is `'%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S.%fZ'`.

This is your code:

```
datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

You should get `2017-08-31 02:24:29` as the value of datetime_object.

Comment: That format is oblivious to the timezone data.

Comment: @ZachGates Why is that?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3306887/3496038).

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a builtin Python's `datautil` module instead of `date time`:

```
import dateutil.parser
value = '2017-08-31T02:24:29.000Z'
result = dateutil.parser.parse(value)
```