# Regex - Slice Date - Aug 22, 2017 02:00 PM EDT

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to take a date, for example `Aug 22, 2017 02:00 PM EDT`
 and get the month, day, year from it.

```
month = re.findall(r'', date)[0]
day = re.findall(r'', date)[0]
year = re.findall(r'', date)[0]
```

I've started with something like this:

```
(.*)(?<=[a-zA-Z]{3}\s)
```

for the month. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first [convert to `datetime`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) and then extract the needed values like this (reusing the example):

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')

print(datetime_object.year, datetime_object.month, datetime_object.day)
```

From what I can see you probably won't need to specify the format but pass the string directly to the `datetime.strptime` function.

Comment: for the `EDT` part I'm trying to add on `%Z` but I keep getting an error. Is that maybe not supported?

Comment: What is the format string that you are using? An example of a failure would be helpful too.

Comment: `Aug 22, 2017 02:00 PM EDT` the end part `EDT` (or could be PST or MST). I used a `%V` but I guess it doesn't know how to interpret it.

Comment: I believe this may be one of the issues described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)