# parse datetime in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, string-formatting

I have a string like `Apr-23-2018_10:57:19_EDT`. Now I want to make a datetime object from it. I am using code in python 3 like below -

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Apr-23-2018_10:57:19_EDT', '%b-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S_%Z')
```

And it is giving me error like below -

```
ValueError: time data 'Apr-23-2018_10:57:19_EDT' does not match format '%b-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S_%Z'
```

Need help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)

Answer (score 1):

Timezones are a mine field.  If you can get away without it you can do something like:

#### Code:

```
datetime_object = dt.datetime.strptime(
    'Apr-23-2018_10:57:19_EDT'[:-4], '%b-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S')
print(datetime_object)
```

#### Result:

```
2018-04-23 10:57:19
```

Comment: Actually, I made a temporary implementation as you stated. But I want to know what is the reason behind this in brief. BTW, kudos for your great effort.

Comment: @RazinTanvir, One big reason is that timezone strings are not unique.  Additionally the libraries dealing with timezone parsing do not always have the same behavior.  Result is that Python's ability to deal with them varies by platform and version.