# Converting Tweet Time Stamps to DD/MM/YY format

Tags: python, twitter

I have a bunch of twitter timestamps in the following format, stored in a csv file e.g. `"Wed Oct 04 17:31:00 +0000 2017"`. How can I convert these to a format like `DD/MM/YY`? Would this require the `dateutil` module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can certainly use the `datetime.strptime` method to accomplish this, I generally have found `dateutil` to be far easier to deal with for timestamps like these:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("Wed Oct 04 17:31:00 +0000 2017").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
'04/10/2017'
```

The pro to using this method is that you don't have to strictly define the input format that you expect, and it works with a [whole bunch of standard formats](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html). The con compared to `strptime` is that it's not quite as explicit as strptime. Depending on your needs one or the other might be better or worse.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with python's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Wed Oct 04 17:31:00 +0000 2017', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
converted_date = datetime_object.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
```