# Python 3.7: converting a string with different timezone into date

Tags: python, datetime, date-conversion, python-3.7

I am trying to convert a string into date format in Python.

I am using following statement

```
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime("Sun Aug 19 16:24:31 PDT 2018", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
```

However, I get an error -

> *ValueError: time data 'Sun Aug 19 16:24:31 PDT 2018' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'*

If I remove the timezone from the date string and the format string, the code works perfect. Which leads me to believe that the issue is related to the timezone but I am not sure what actions should be taken. 
I am in eastern timezone and the time zone in the string is in Pacific timezone.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525115/5299969) you can use [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) for this:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser

>>> datetime_obj = parser.parse("Sun Aug 19 16:24:31 PDT 2018")
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 16, 24, 31)
```

Standard [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) behaves very strangely with parsing timezones, as I see reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3306887/5299969) in question related to similar problem.