# Parse Date String to UTC UNIX Format

Tags: python, time, timezone, unix-timestamp, utc

I have a timestamp in string format

```
timestamp_str = '18:02:19 14:14:11 465872'
format_str = '%y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S %f'
```

and to convert it to UTC in UNIX I have written the following code

```
def str2utc(timestr,formatstr):
    timeobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr, formatstr)
    time_utc = time.mktime(timeobj.timetuple())
    return time_utc

timestamp_utc_unix = str2utc(timestamp_str,format_str)
```

Nevertheless, as I already know, this does not work if my system time is something else than utc. I have read other posts like

[Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)

but just cannot wrap my head around how to correct it. How do I have to change the code so that not matter what my system time is it always outputs utc in unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

> Note
>
> There is no method to obtain the POSIX timestamp directly from a naive datetime instance representing UTC time. If your application uses this convention and your system timezone is not set to UTC, you can obtain the POSIX timestamp by supplying tzinfo=timezone.utc:
>
> `timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()`
>
> or by calculating the timestamp directly:
>
> `timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)`

So your function would look like

```
def str2utc(timestr,formatstr):
    timeobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr, formatstr)
    time_utc = timeobj.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezon.utc).timestamp()
    return time_utc
```

I'm getting a value of `1519049651.465872`, which matches what I get from unixtimestamp.com