# What does -xxxx means in date time format? And how to compare it?

Tags: python, date, datetime

In the following representation of date time, what does `-0600` means? And how it can be used to compare dates?

```
Tue, 27 Nov 2018 14:59:32 -0600
```

Tagging it with Python as looking for date comparison.

Comment: I think it is showing your timezone -6 hours from GMT.

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525115/2823755).

Comment: @wwii the same answer I just did +1 thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

`-0600` is the timezone offset.  Use the `%z` directive of [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to use it when making a new datetime object.

```
import datetime
s1 = 'Tue, 27 Nov 2018 14:59:32 -0600'
s2 = 'Tue, 27 Nov 2018 15:59:32 -0500'
s3 = 'Tue, 27 Nov 2018 14:59:32 -0500'

fmt = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'

dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(s1, fmt)        
dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(s2, fmt)        
dt3 = datetime.datetime.strptime(s3, fmt)
```

---

```
>>> dt1
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 27, 14, 59, 32, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 64800)))
>>> dt2
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 27, 15, 59, 32, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)))
>>> dt3
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 27, 14, 59, 32, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400)))
>>> dt1 == dt2
True
>>> dt1 == dt3
False
>>> dt1 > dt3
True
>>>
```

Comment: probably a duplicate - but I couldn't find an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This will parse date:

```
datetime_obj = parser.parse(item["last_modified"])
```

Python script to compare date

```
from dateutil import parser

datetime_obj = parser.parse(item["last_modified"])

if datetime_obj > some_date_obj
```