# ValueError: time data 'Tue, 19 Nov 2019 09:00 EST' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M %Z'

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

So the title is quite self explanatory: I was trying to `datetime.strptime(news.date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M %Z')` and it didn't work out for `Tue, 19 Nov 2019 09:00 EST` but got a `ValueError`. I tried to use `datetime.strptime(news.date[:-4], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M')` and it all works just fine. How do I fix this timezone issue?

Update: the timezone will be used later, so I do need to process it as well

Comment: Sounds like there may be a problem with your system's timezone DB, it doesn't contain `EST`.

Comment: `strptime` only accepts timezones present in `time.tzname`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)