# Converting string (with timezone) to datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-conversion

I aim to convert

```
stringtime = '2020-02-30 10:27:00+01:00'
```

so that I can compare it to

```
nowtime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

using

```
if nowtime > stringtime:
    print(1)
```

I tried `strptime`:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(stringtime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But cannot find a format specification for the timezone in the strptime documentation.

I also tried

```
pandas.Timestamp(stringtime)
```

but I get `ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)

Answer (score 2):

```py
datetime.datetime.strptime(stringtime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
```

Will give you the expected result `%z` is the format (Python3 only), however your original date is invalid as February doesnt have 30 days :)

Comment: got it working by adding .replace(tzinfo=tzutc()) to both variables

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Your `stringtime` is wrong, there exists no February 30th. ;)

You can achieve what you want with `dateutil`:

```
import dateutil.parser
stringtime = '2020-03-30 10:27:00+01:00'
dateutil.parser.isoparse(stringtime)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 27, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```

Comment: This will throw a TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes :(

Comment: got it working by adding .replace(tzinfo=tzutc()) to both variables