# Converting column in Dataframe to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've been trying to use the to_datetime function to convert values in my column to datetime:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],errors='coerce',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z')
```

After that, I received only NaT values.

Example: Value Format in Column: '1979-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC'

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], utc=True)`?

Comment: After that, I get an error: Unknown string format: 1979-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't parse utc offset (+0000) and timeszone information at the sime time.

You might want to remove the UTC at the end and only parse the offset.

```
df['date'] = df.date.str[:-4]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
```

Comment: It worked, I changed it to:
df.date = df.date.astype(str)
df['date'] = df.date.str[:-3] 
and then
 df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], utc=True)
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can't manage both `%z` and `%Z` as you can see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx#L83). Note that Python's `strptime` can handle this, but [doesn't deal with `%Z`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones).

In your case you might want to just peel off the last bit with `ser.str` and consider opening a feature request.