# How to get month and year from date

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a date in this format - `2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z`, this is coming from an API. How do I get the month (e.g. April) and year (e.g. 2020) from this date using the datetime module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package to parse ISO 8601 dates.

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.isoparse('2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z')
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Then you can retrieve the month and year from the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object it returns.

Comment: Thank you! Solved it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do using **datetime** module you can do this as

```
from datetime import datetime
input_dt = '2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z'
dt_object = datetime.strptime(input_dt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fz")
```

Now you can do

```
dt_object.year
dt_object.day
dt_object.month
```

> The strptime() method creates a datetime object from the given string.

Comment: This ignores the timezone.

Comment: @BertrandMarron "When the %z directive is provided to the strptime() method, an aware datetime object will be produced. The tzinfo of the result will be set to a timezone instance." as it says here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones

Comment: Your code will not work with `2020-01-31T00:00:00.000+04:00`, for instance.