# Convert string with timezone included into datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have the following string format:
`date = 'Jun 8, 2021 PDT'`
I'm trying to convert that string into a `datetime` object. Right now I have it at:

`dt_o = dt.strptime(date, '%b %d, %Y')`

That gets me almost all the way there, but I am still getting the following error:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains:  PDT

Is there a way to include the `'PDT'` in the original creation of the `datetime` object?. My other option is to strip the string of the `'PDT'` and create a timezone unaware object.

`dt_o = dt.strptime(date.rsplit(None, 1)[0], '%b %d, %Y')` gives me an object of: `datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 8, 0, 0)`.

is there a way I can apply the `PDT` timezone to that? I'd need to be able to convert it from the string `date.rsplit(None, 1)[1]`, since it won't always be `PDT`

Comment: You meant `rsplit` and not `rstrip` ?

Comment: related: [time data '07-18-2018 09:35AM PDT' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y %I:%M%p %Z' (match)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67797919/10197418)

Comment: @azro yes, thanks. Updated.

Comment: related: [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3305413/10197418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common misconception that `%Z` can parse arbitrary abbreviated time zone names. It cannot. See especially the "Notes" section #6 under [technical detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) in the docs.

You'll have to do that "by hand" since many of those abbreviations are ambiguous. Here's an option how to deal with it using only the standard lib:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

# we need to define which abbreviation corresponds to which time zone
zoneMapping = {'PDT' : ZoneInfo('America/Los_Angeles'),
               'PST' : ZoneInfo('America/Los_Angeles'),
               'CET' : ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin'),
               'CEST': ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin')}

# some example inputs; last should fail
timestrings = ('Jun 8, 2021 PDT', 'Feb 8, 2021 PST', 'Feb 8, 2021 CET',
               'Aug 9, 2020 WTF')

for t in timestrings:
    # we can split off the time zone abbreviation
    s, z = t.rsplit(' ', 1)
    # parse the first part to datetime object
    # and set the time zone; use dict.get if it should be None if not found
    dt = datetime.strptime(s, "%b %d, %Y").replace(tzinfo=zoneMapping[z])
    print(t, "->", dt)
```

gives

```
Jun 8, 2021 PDT -> 2021-06-08 00:00:00-07:00
Feb 8, 2021 PST -> 2021-02-08 00:00:00-08:00
Feb 8, 2021 CET -> 2021-02-08 00:00:00+01:00

Traceback (most recent call last):

    dt = datetime.strptime(s, "%b %d, %Y").replace(tzinfo=zoneMapping[z])

KeyError: 'WTF'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the documentation at all?

```
dt_o = dt.strptime(date, '%b %d, %Y %Z')
```