# Why does Python's datetime strptime() not set timezone when %Z is specified in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-datetime

Let's say I have the string:

```py
combined_datetime_string = "July 04, 2021 12:00:00 PM MST"
```

and I parse it to a datetime object via:

```py
from datetime import datetime 
dateobj = datetime.strptime(combined_datetime_string, '%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p %Z')
```

Why does Django, then, complain that **RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Task.deadline received a naive datetime (2021-07-04 12:00:00) while time zone support is active**?

Of course, I could set the timezone manually on the datetime object, but that seems unnecessary. I'd have to extract the `MST` part (or equivalent) of the string and figure out what timezone object that corresponds to. Shouldn't the `%Z` part of the original string be able to set the timezone correctly?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code gives `ValueError: time data 'July 04, 2021 12:00:00 PM MST' does not match format '%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p %Z'`

Comment: It's running fine for me... huh. I've double-checked that I copied it over correctly.

Comment: I guess it depends on what time zone you're in whether it will parse correctly.

Comment: Looks related: https://bugs.python.org/issue22377

Comment: Why would that be, if the timezone is being directly specified (MST)?

Comment: @khelwood all that is saying is that back in 2014 it wouldn't recognize some timezone strings. It's definitely seems to be recognizing MST in this case.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3305413/3890632

Comment: It also says that datetimes parsed without `%z` are naive (even if they use `%Z`).

Comment: You nailed it there -- I think I'll try python-dateutil. Thanks!!