# UNIX time out of a string with UTC offset and time zone

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I want to compute the UNIX time out of a string in Python. My string contains both the UTC offset AND the timezone in brackets, as shown below.

The timezone `(PDT)` is troublesome as my code works until then. `datestring1` is converted correctly, but `datestring2` isn't.

```py
import time
import datetime

datestring1 = "Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700"
datestring2 = "Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700 (PDT)"
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring1, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z").timetuple())
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring2, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)").timetuple())
```

Comment: `PDT` is just an ambiguous abbreviation, not a timezone name. Check the [list of abbreviations](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/). There are 3 BSTs (Bangladesh, Bougainville, British), 3 ISTs (Indian, Irish, Israel) etc. If you know the string contains an offset it's better to just strip the abbreviation before parsing

Comment: see also: my [answer on Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69673614/10197418)

Comment: note #2: `time.mktime` is not needed, you have a method [.timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) for datetime objects (which is more readable as well I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `python-dateutil`. Take a look at the answer here: [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)

It seems others have also had trouble parsing Timezone names using `%Z`.

In your case that would be:

```py
import time
import datetime
from dateutil import parser

datestring1 = "Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700"
datestring2 = "Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700 (PDT)"

print(time.mktime(parser.parse(datestring1).timetuple()))
print(time.mktime(parser.parse(datestring2).timetuple()))
```

Comment: `others have also had trouble parsing Timezone names` that's because `PDT` isn't a timezone name, it's an ambiguous abbreviation. Ambiguous means more than one timezone may have the same abbreviation, eg IST is Indian, Irish, Israel, BST is Bangladesh, Bougainville, British. The de-facto standard names are the IANA [timezone database names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)  eg `America/Los_Angeles`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) aren't precise here as well I think, "*`%Z`: Time zone name [...] UTC, GMT*" (UTC isn't even a time zone...). The false assumption that `%Z` can parse arbitrary tz name abbreviations isn't that far-fetched.

Comment: @MrFuppes that documentation was also what I looked at but was unsure of. After looking at #6 under the `Notes` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) I guess it depends on the user's location

Comment: yes, even after the 2019 update, the docs are misleading. Python's `strptime` falls back to the platform's C library for this I think, so *on some platforms*, `%Z` will accept the local time's current abbreviation (e.g. "EST" if you're in New York during summer). Other than that, it is only good for *ignoring* "UTC" or "GMT", it doesn't actually parse those to a timezone object `datetime.timezone.utc`. At least on my platform (Win 10).