# strptime() gives ValueError: time data 'AM CDT' does not match format '%p %Z'

Tags: python, datetime

I have a str that I want to convert to a datetime. This str is this: 'Thursday, September 9, 2021 at 11:50 AM CDT. I am using the datetime.strptime() function, but it seems like the AM or time zone is not being recognized.

When I use the code

```
time = 'Thursday, September 9, 2021 at 11:50 AM CDT'
time = datetime.strptime(time, '%A, %B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p %Z')
```

I get the following:
`ValueError: time data 'Thursday, September 9, 2021 at 11:50 AM CDT' does not match format '%A, %B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p %Z:%M %p %Z'`

I've been able to convert the first part up until the %p %Z part, at which I get the following error:

`ValueError: time data 'AM CDT' does not match format '%p %Z'`

Any ideas on how dt.strptime() can recognize AM/PM and the time zone correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the best approach, but since Python 3.9 you can use the [`ZoneInfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module for this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo


CDT = ZoneInfo('CST6CDT')
# or alternatively:
# CDT = ZoneInfo('US/Central')

time = 'Thursday, September 9, 2021 at 1:50 PM'
time = datetime.strptime(time, '%A, %B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p')
time = time.replace(tzinfo=CDT)

print(time)  # 2021-09-09 13:50:00-05:00
```

---

@MrFuppes made a good point about an ambiguity between the `CST6EDT` and `US/Central` zones. However, when I tried a quick test in DST and outside of DST, I couldn't see any noticeable difference, as the time zone seemed to adjust automatically - which indicates that either of those zone values appear to be DST- aware (unless I'm missing something of course).

I added an example below:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo


# CDT = ZoneInfo('CST6CDT')
CDT = ZoneInfo('US/Central')

# Note: DST in 2021, ends on November 7th
time_dst = 'Saturday, November 6, 2021 at 1:50 PM'
time_st = 'Monday, November 8, 2021 at 1:50 PM'

time_dst = datetime.strptime(time_dst, '%A, %B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p')
time_dst = time_dst.replace(tzinfo=CDT)
time_st = datetime.strptime(time_st, '%A, %B %d, %Y at %I:%M %p')
time_st = time_st.replace(tzinfo=CDT)

print('DST: ', time_dst)
print('ST:  ', time_st)
```

Output appears to be the same despite which `ZoneInfo` object is used:

```
DST:  2021-11-06 13:50:00-05:00
ST:   2021-11-08 13:50:00-06:00
```

Comment: I think you actually want a time zone like US/Central

Comment: I actually couldn't find any info on that. Is there any difference between US/Central and CST6CDT?

Comment: This is a start, but I actually have a series of observations (all strings) with the date above.  The timezone is constantly changing like the other times. Currently looking into timezone though about UTC codes.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes I think it's just a constant offset of 6 hours, see https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/8b409e22d7e1b70bf9364b014a8e359908a507a9/northamerica#L204 - a US Central time zone would have DST, so UTC +6/+5

Comment: @MrFuppes I tried to test with the US/Central zone as suggested, but I didn't find any noticeable difference in output between CST6CDT, which further adds to the ambiguity I suppose. I updated my answer above if you're interested.

Comment: If the OP has multiple time zone abbreviations to parse, I think the dateutil approach (tzinfos mapping dict) is a nice way, see the dupe I linked. I think I also wrote an answer using a similar technique + zoneinfo somewhere on SO ;-)