# Converting a formatted time string to milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am trying to convert `'2015-09-15T17:13:29.380Z'` to milliseconds.

At first I used:

```
time.mktime(
  datetime.datetime.strptime(
    "2015-09-15T17:13:29.380Z",
    "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
  ).timetuple()
)
```

I got `1442330009.0` - with no microseconds.  I think `time.mktime` rounds the number to the nearest second.

In the end I did:

```
origTime = '2015-09-15T17:13:29.380Z'
tupleTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(origTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
microsecond = tupleTime.microsecond
updated = float(time.mktime(tupleTime.timetuple())) + (microsecond * 0.000001)
```

Is there a **better way to do this** and how do I **work with the timezone**?

Answer (score 9):

Your input time is in UTC; it is incorrect to use `time.mktime()` here unless your local timezone is always UTC.

There are two steps:

1. **Convert the input rfc 3339 time string into a datetime object that represents time in UTC**

   ```
   from datetime import datetime

   utc_time = datetime.strptime("2015-09-15T17:13:29.380Z",
                                "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
   ```

   You've already done it. See also [Convert an RFC 3339 time to a standard Python timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1941927/4279)
2. **Convert UTC time to POSIX time expressed in milliseconds**:

   ```
   from datetime import datetime, timedelta

   milliseconds = (utc_time - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) // timedelta(milliseconds=1)
   # -> 1442337209380
   ```

   For a version that works on Python 2.6-3+, see [How can I convert a datetime object to milliseconds since epoch (unix time) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6999726/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no miliseconds in `timetuple`. However, you don't need `timetuple`. For timestamp, just call

```
datetime.strptime(...).timestamp()
```

As for timezone, check out `tzinfo` argument of `datetime`.

**EDIT**: `tzinfo`

```
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 15, 17, 13, 29, 380000)
>>> d.timestamp()
1442330009.38
>>> import pytz
>>> d.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")).timestamp()
1442355209.38
```

Comment: `.timestamp()` assumes that the input is in the local timezone -- it will return a wrong result here unless the local timezone is UTC.

Comment: it is incorrect to use `.replace(tzinfo=pytz_tz)` with pytz timezone that has non-fixed utc offset (read the note at the very top of pytz docs).