# How to validate that a string is a time in RFC3339 format?

Tags: python, date, validation, timezone, rfc3339

I have the following string `'2012-10-09T19:00:55Z'` and I want to verify it's in `RFC3339` time format.

One (wrong) approach would be to do something like the following:

```
datetime.strptime('2012-10-09T19:00:55Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

The issue here is that this return a non time zone aware object as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941927/convert-an-rfc-3339-time-to-a-standard-python-timestamp).

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
from datetime import datetime

assert datetime.strptime('2012-10-09T19:00:55Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
assert datetime.strptime('2012-10-09T19:00:55Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').tzinfo is not None
```

Notice the subtle difference in the string format. This makes sure that the datetime object is time zone aware.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522251/whats-the-difference-between-iso-8601-and-rfc-3339-date-formats/522281#522281 - I think your format code is a bit strict ;-) Maybe a `regex` would be a cleaner way to *verify* the string's compliance with RFC3339?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.